# What are a few Fast C Math Libraries?

Tags: math, c

I have seen quite a few nice math libraries for C++ (Eigen, GLM, etc), but I notice they are all C++ only and my program is written strictly in C. I need a fast native C library for math, especially linear algebra, and would rather not write a wrapper for Eigen. What are some recommended libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, most modern math libraries are written on C++ or Python, but there are also old libraries (originally written in Fortran) for math exist:

- [GSL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/): as stated in a name, it's a *scientific* library, there are a variety of a math branches supported, including linear algebra, statistics, different integration methods, series, optimization procedures and much more.
- [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) and [BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas/): two very old, supported and efficient libraries for linear algebra, `LAPACK` is used in *Matlab*, *Mathematica* and other mathematics software for linear algebra support.
- [ATLAS](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/): from the project site:

> ATLAS's purpose is to provide portably optimal linear algebra software.

Comment: "This can be a good . . ." - don't keep me in suspense! :-)

Comment: @NeilSlater oh... Now I'm curious too!

Comment: It is an incomplete sentence, I thought maybe you had clicked "submit" before you finished. I suggested some changes of phrasing as an edit.